# R -find and replace within a script, iteratively

Tags: r, replace, iteration

I have a somewhat complex script that is working well. It imports multiple `.csvs`, combines them, adjusts them, re-sorts them and writes them out as multiple new `.csvs`. All good.

The problem is that I need to run this script on each of 2100 files. Each `.csv` file has a name incorporating a seven or eight digit non-numeric string which also has other specific identifiers. There are numerous files with the same string suffix and the script works on all of them at once. An example of the naming system:

```
gfdlesm2g_45Fall_17100202.csv
ccsm4_45Fall_10270102.csv
bnuesm_45Fall_5130205.csv
mirocesmchem_45Fall_5010007.csv
```

The script begins with `fnames <- dir("~/Desktop/modified_files/", pattern = "*_45Fall_1030001.csv")`

And I need to replace the "1030001", in this case, with the next number. Right now I am using Find and Replace in RStudio to replace the seven (or eight) digit number each time the script has completed. I know there has to be a better way than to do this all manually for 2100 files.

All the research I've found is for iterating within a dataframe or whatever, in the columns or rows, and I can't process how to make this work for my needs.

I am thinking that if I made a vector of all the numbers (really they're names), like `"01080204", "01090003", "01100001", "18020116", "18020125", "15080303", "16020301", "03170006", "04010101", "04010201", etc`

There must be a way to say, in code, "now pick the next name, and run the script". I looked at the `lapply, mapply, sapply` family and couldn't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I don't understand why either `sapply` or `lapply` are not doing what you want. There is a `list.files()` function that should deliver a vector that can be used as a first argument to either one of those for the purpose you describe. Do a search on SO using those terms and you will find hundreds of asked and answered questions. If you pick your pattern argument sensibly, say "_45Fall_", you shouldn't even need to do any replacements.

Comment: I didn't say they weren't doing what I wanted, I said I didn't know how to use them. I am entirely self-taught and have only been doing this for 2 1/2 months. I tried your pattern search suggestion and got `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8 Kb` .

Comment: You tried.  Something. But you didn’t [edit] your question body to show what “it” really was.  And you didn’t show “what” “it” wa seeing some to.

Comment: What is the pattern in filenames that you are looking for? For example, if you want all the files that follow a pattern `'_45Fall_somenumbers.csv'` you can try `fnames <- list.files("~/Desktop/modified_files/", pattern = "*_45Fall_\\d+\\.csv$")`. Does `fnames` have the files that you want?

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks, no. It appears to have used the 'somenumbers' from the previous script (I've been doing it manually), combined with the last season. The full script contains sections not only for Fall, but Win, Spr, Sum. But I only used one section, I used the Fall, but I got "45Sum" results. I don't know what the code you sent is supposed to mean, but it does not choose all the "somenumbers", it only gave results for one set.

Comment: fnames <- dir("~/Desktop/RprojPuddle/modified_files/", pattern = "*_45Win_01010002.csv")
read_data <- function(z){
   dat <- fread(z, skip = 0, select = 1:3, )
   return(dat[1:(nrows=56)])}
datalist <- lapply(fnames, read_data)
bigdata <- rbindlist(datalist, use.names = T)
datalist = do.call("rbind", bigdata)
splitByHUCs <- split(bigdata, f = bigdata$HUC8 , sep = "\n", lex.order = TRUE)
saveFun_WRITE <- function(splitByHUCs, name_i) {
   fwrite(splitByHUCs, file = paste0("~/Desktop/TEST/xplay/", name_i, ".csv"))
mapply(FUN = saveFun_WRITE, splitByHUCs, name_i = names(splitByHUCs))

Comment: This, above, is 1/4 of the full script - one season, "Win". I don't know how it would help because, to my mind, it's only the "function" that I want the iterative script to perform, so shouldn't be important, but maybe will help with understanding the complexity of the files. I tried to show in the OP that there are multiple prefixes as well as multiple suffixes and it seems to me that might be what's messing up when there are too many wildcards.

Comment: Someone closed the post who didn't understand what I was asking. I am not asking to merely list files. I will ask again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for pattern in files `_45Fall_` you can use `list.files`.

```
fnames <- list.files("~/Desktop/modified_files/", pattern = "*_45Fall_\\d+\\.csv$")
```